# python3 return all variables in lists

Tags: list, python-3.x

```
def get_resources(*required):
    """
    This is to help building functions in the main calculator faster
    returns lists of resources needed, in the order requested
    """
    print('-'*30)
    a = ['acceleration', 0, 'a', 'm s⁻²', '.2f', 'scalar']
    A = ['amplitude', 0, 'A', 'm', '.2f', 'scalar']  # A: amplitude
    Em = ['combined mass', 0, '∑m', 'kg', '.2f', 'scalar']
    f = ['frequency', 0, 'f', 'Hz', '.1f', 'scalar']  # f: frequency (also m s⁻¹)
    F = ['force', 0, 'F', 'N', '.2f', 'scalar']
    g = ['gravity', 9.81, 'a', 'm s⁻²', '.2f', 'scalar']
    hl = ['wavelength', 0, 'λ', 'm', '.2f','vector']  # λ: wavelength
    m = ['mass', 0, 'm', 'kg', '.2f', 'scalar']
    m1 = ['mass1', 0, 'm1', 'kg', '.2f', 'scalar']
    m2 = ['mass2', 0, 'm2', 'kg', '.2f', 'scalar']
    t = ['time', 0, 't', 's', '.2f', 'scalar']
    T = ['tension', 0, 'T', 'N', '.1f', 'scalar']
    T = ['period', 0, 'T', 's', '.3f', 'scalar']  # T: Time PERIOD of oscillation in seconds (T = 2π√(m/k))
    v = ['wave speed', 0, 'v', 'm s⁻¹', '.2f', 'scalar']  # v: speed of a wave (v = fλ OR v = λ/T)
    v = ['velocity', 0, 'v', 'm s⁻¹', '.2f', 'scalar']
    v0 = ['initial velocity', 0, 'v₀', 'm s⁻¹', '.2f', 'vector']
    vf = ['final velocity', 0, 'vf', 'm s⁻¹', '.2f', 'vector']
    x = ['change in distance', 0, 'Δx', 'm', '.2f', 'scalar']
    x = ['distance', 0, 'x', 'm', '.2f', 'scalar']
    for i in required:
        for j in vars().items():
            if i == j[0]: print('{} = {}'.format(j[0], j[1]))
```

I am trying to write a function (that takes arguments) and then compares those against the values in the function, and prints all possible matches. However it is not printing all possible matches, only the final ones that match the name. Also I would like to use an alphabetical character in the list [1] position, eg x = ['distance', 0, 'x', 'm', '.2f', 'scalar'] > x = ['distance', ABC, 'x', 'm', '.2f', 'scalar']

At the moment If I do

```
get_resources('x','F', 'T')
```

It will print

```
------------------------------
x = ['distance', 0, 'x', 'm', '.2f', 'scalar']
F = ['force', 0, 'F', 'N', '.2f', 'scalar']
T = ['period', 0, 'T', 's', '.3f', 'scalar']
```

but I would like to print like this.

```
------------------------------
x = ['change in distance', xc, 'Δx', 'm', '.2f', 'scalar']
x = ['distance', xc, 'x', 'm', '.2f', 'scalar']
F = ['force', Fc, 'F', 'N', '.2f', 'scalar']
T = ['tension', Tc, 'T', 'N', '.1f', 'scalar']
T = ['period', Tc, 'T', 's', '.3f', 'scalar']
```

How to rewrite this function to return the results as required?

Comment: To what do you want to compare? The *actual* variable names, the third item in each list, or any item in any list? If I search for `a`, should 'amplitude' also show up, or even things that are sc`a`lar? If I search for 'N', should that return 'tension' and 'force'?

Comment: I want to compare the required name, eg 'T' against all the items in the function, that are 'T' = [list]. I am not returning anything, just printing results. Maybe that is cause confusion.

Comment: You're still not saying what you want to match on: the variable name itself, or something else?

Comment: Match on the variable name I believe. However I'm not sure how to explain exactly in words, just in examples.

Comment: If you store the variables in a dict (with their names as keys), it's as easy as `if 'T' in variables` or `variables[T]`.

Comment: Note that either with the dict, or with what you're currently doing, you have a problem: you use `T` twice, overwriting itself. You may want to store the value for every variable in a list (of lists). So that `T` returns a list of length 2, while `F` returns a list of length 1.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the issue, unfortunately I have to remove the comments.. ah well

`def get_resources(*required):
    """
    This is to help building functions in the main calculator faster
    returns lists of resources needed, in the order requested
    """
    print('-'*30)
    longstring = \
    "a = ['acceleration', ac, 'a', 'm s⁻²', '.2f', 'scalar'] | " \
    "A = ['amplitude', 0, 'Ac', 'm', '.2f', 'scalar'] | " \
    "Em = ['combined mass', Emc, '∑m', 'kg', '.2f', 'scalar'] | " \
    "f = ['frequency', fc, 'f', 'Hz', '.1f', 'scalar'] | " \
    "F = ['force', Fc, 'F', 'N', '.2f', 'scalar'] | " \
    "g = ['gravity', 9.81, 'a', 'm s⁻²', '.2f', 'scalar'] | " \
    "hl = ['wavelength', hlc, 'λ', 'm', '.2f', 'vector'] | " \
    "KE = ['kinetic energy', KEc, 'KE', 'J', '.1f', 'scalar'] | " \
    "m = ['mass', 0, 'mc', 'kg', '.2f', 'scalar'] | " \
    "m1 = ['mass1', m1c, 'm1', 'kg', '.2f', 'scalar'] | " \
    "m2 = ['mass2', m2c, 'm2', 'kg', '.2f', 'scalar'] | " \
    "t = ['time', tc, 't', 's', '.2f', 'scalar'] | " \
    "T = ['tension force', Tc, 'T', 'N', '.1f', 'scalar'] | " \
    "T = ['period', Tc, 'T', 's', '.3f', 'scalar'] | "
    "v = ['wave speed', vc, 'v', 'm s⁻¹', '.2f', 'scalar'] | " \
    "v = ['velocity', vc, 'v', 'm s⁻¹', '.2f', 'scalar'] | " \
    "v0 = ['initial velocity', v0c, 'v₀', 'm s⁻¹', '.2f', 'vector'] | " \
    "vf = ['final velocity', vfc, 'vf', 'm s⁻¹', '.2f', 'vector'] | " \
    "W = ['work', Wc, 'W','J', '.2f', 'scalar']  # W: work (W = Fd) | " \
    "x = ['change in distance', xc, 'Δx', 'm', '.2f', 'scalar'] | " \ 
    "x = ['distance', xc, 'x', 'm', '.2f', 'scalar'] | "
    variables = (longstring.split('|'))
    for i in required:
        for j in variables:
            k = j.split('=')
            k[0] = k[0].strip()
            if i == k[0]:
                k[1] = k[1].strip()
                print('{} = {}'.format(k[0], k[1]))
get_resources('m1', 'm2', 'T', 'a', 'g', 't', 'x', 'v0')
get_resources('m','v','KE','x','F', 'T')`